# Stored procedure privilege error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I tried to execute this stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS HelloWorld|
CREATE PROCEDURE HelloWorld()
BEGIN
UPDATE sites_niche SET `short_review` = REPLACE(`short_review`, 'â€™',"'");
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

However, it tells me this:

> Access denied for user 'bestcam728'@'%' to database 'bestcamdir_main'

The problem is that I am already logged into the database.. that error prevents me from creating stored procedures... how do I overcome this?
Also there is a problem of not being able to create new users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `SHOW GRANTS` command to view all privileges user 'bestcam728'@'%' has.

To grant privileges to 'bestcam728'@'%' connect as root and give privileges you need using [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) statement. It seems that CREATE or CREATE ROUTINE privilege is missing. You can grant these privileges globally or for specific database -

```
-- Grant database privileges
GRANT CREATE ON `bestcamdir_main`.* TO 'bestcam728'@'%';
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE ON `bestcamdir_main`.* TO 'bestcam728'@'%';

-- Grant global privileges
GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'bestcam728'@'%';
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE ON *.* TO 'bestcam728'@'%';
```

Then reconnect as 'bestcam728'@'%' and try to create procedure again.

Comment: it has the following privilege: GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON `bestcamdir\_main`.* TO 'bestcam728'@'%'

Comment: i have no idea how to reconnect as another user. I go to my host, then go to phpmyadmin,,and i find myself as that user

Comment: What is the `bestcamdir\_main`? Are you sure you are using correct database? `bestcamdir\_main` vs `bestcamdir_main`

Comment: bestcamdir_main... and that is my username  bestcam728..the password however isnt %, .. it is something else when i form a connection between the webserver and the database

Comment: To reconnect as root you should edit phpmyadmin config file and specify user and password. Find this information in the product documentation. If you can access MySQL server using another client, then you can try Security Manager tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express edition).

Comment: The '%' in user's host name means that user 'bestcam728' can connect from any host.

Comment: I am not a db.. may be my host provider should do that..cause i think they can only log as the root... My permissions are already set, and I cant create any users and I cant grant privileges

Comment: I only can say that to create procedure it is enough to have 'CREATE ROUTINE' privilege.  But I'm not sure that you use correct database, check it one more time. The error says about 'bestcamdir_main' database, the SHOW GRANTS says about `bestcamdir\_main` database.

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions in mysql.db and potentially mysql.user.

Comment: I wish i knew how to do it.. is there a way to do it in phpmyadmin , simply grant permissions to everyone

Comment: Try running GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bestcam728'@'%'; and if it doesn't work you should add the identified by 'password'; and see if that works. I have seen identified by 'password' required for some grants. You can also grant the create/execute as written below.

Comment: I did this: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bestcam728'@'%' identified by 'my pass' and got this:  Access denied for user 'bestcam728'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: Are you the actual owner/admin of this database? It might seem you dont have the required GRANT priv on the user you are logging in with?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and log in as root. You can then grant the correct privileges for the user to create stored procedures.

Comment: problem is that even if I do this: GRANT ALL ON bestcamdir_main.* TO 'bestcams'@'%' .. I get the same error